# Expected expression before 'char'

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, fgets

I'm having a pretty hard time working on this assignment I have for one of my CSC classes. I am making a character array from my name (ie John Doe). I need to pass a pointer of my character array into a function that outputs the number of characters stored in your character array. Then I need the function to also return this integer back to my main function.

If anyone would like to help me in advanced

- I need to spell it completely backwards. i.e. (eoD nhoJ)
- I need to inform the user of which element of my array the space in there name is. I also need to return this value as well.
- Then last but not least I need to reverse the name i.e. (Doe John)

Please help me with this. I've only posted the part of the assignment I've actually managed to figure out. Thank you all in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char name [25]={'\0'};

    fgets(name,sizeof(name),stdin); 

    printf("You Entered: %s     \n", name);

    printf("There are %u characters. \n", strlen(char * name));
}
```

Comment: Use `strlen(name)`, without the type name

Comment: What exactly is it that you don't understand with the tasks 1, 2, 3? On Stack Overflow, it is considered off-topic to ask for code solutions for things that you don't understand yourself. So unless your clarify this, there is a risk that your question gets closed.

Comment: I was hoping someone could give me an example using my code. I'm a student still learning this. How am I supposed to learn something if I don't ask how to do something I don't understand.

Comment: @user2172993 You are supposed to do research on your own. This is pretty basic (should I say trivial) stuff -- you can find literally dozens of places (questions and answers on Stack Overflow and elsewhere) where this problem is already solved/answered. You should also consult an introductory-level C language tutorial. All in all, the first steps shall be made by you.

Answer (score 2):

```
strlen(char * name) ==> strlen(name)
```

You should not use char * before string while calculating length

**EDIT**

If your intention is to write your own function for some practice.

declare function

```
 unsigned int my_strlen(char *); //argument needed is character pointer
```

And define

```
unsigned int my_strlen(char *str) 
      {   
        //find length..  
         return length;
      }
```

Function call

```
   printf("There are %u characters. \n", my_strlen(name)); // passing starting address of character array to a function.
```

Here also you should not use `char *` before name.

All your questions can easily found on Google. just doing simple search you can found.

If you want to do them by your self. you need to read c tutorials.

Comment: But I need to pass a pointer array so don't I need to use an asterisk to get the pointer location?

Comment: Here name is a character array.To Find the length of character array with the help of strlen(), you just need to pass array name.And character array is different from pointer array. see    http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen  for strlen() explanation.

Comment: "You might want to declare your own function to find length of character array" - why would anyone want to do that?

Comment: OP stated "I need to pass a pointer of my character array into a function that outputs the number of characters stored in your character array."

Comment: @Gangadhar And why is `strlen()` not good enough then? It does exactly that.

Comment: `strlen()` is worth enough. But reading the question I was understood OP wants to write own function to find length.

Answer (score 0):

Change:
    printf("There are %u characters. \n", strlen(char * name));
by:
    printf("There are %u characters. \n", strlen(name));